# Save jquery's $(window).scrollTop() as PHP $_SESSION['scroll_pos'] variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I am sending `post` data to a page that runs a `MySql` statement then returns via a page redirect

```
header("location: {$_SERVER['HTTP-REFERER']}");
```

I am trying to use `Ajax` to send the `$(window).scrollTop()` value as a `$_GET['scroll_pos']` variable like so:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

$(document).ready(function(){

    // SET SCROLL SESSION VARIABLE
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var xmlhttp;

        if( window.XMLHttpRequest ){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'script_files/set_scroll_session.php?scroll_pos=' +
          $(window).scrollTop(), true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    });

    // SCROLL TO $_SESSION['scroll_pos'];
    $(window).scrollTop(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['scroll_pos']); ?>); // <-- THIS IS NOT FIRING

});
```

The `set_scroll_session.php` page saves the `$_GET['scroll_pos']` as a `$_SESSION['scroll_pos']` variable like so

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // VARIABLES
    $scroll_pos = $_GET['scroll_pos'];

    $_SESSION['scroll_pos'] = $scroll_pos;

?>
```

which needs to be called as seen in the above `$(document).ready()` function.

The window is not scrolling to amount specified in the `$_SESSION['scroll_pos']` variable, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are already using jquery so I would highly recommend (however, it's not necessary) that you use jquerys built in AJAX method.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And the reason it's not working is because you can't `echo` out a value to be used in javascript like that, you must use AJAX to fetch that value, then set the scroll position.

```
//WILL NOT WORK!!!!
$(window).scrollTop(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['scroll_pos']); ?>);
```

Or better yet, save the scroll position in a cookie or local storage to avoid an unnecessary call to the server...

Comment: I ended up using the cookie method using a jquery plugin called [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Thanks for the jquery ajax reference, will definitely start using that.